# trying to display filtered question once at a time so when it is submitted it show the next question and also scores it to the score tally

Tags: javascript, html

So currently I'm creating a quiz that filters out questions from an array based on the difficult key. At the moment when the difficulty is chosen it will showcase all the questions from the difficulty in a list. I want to show each question once then score it when I submit it then show the next. Here is the code:

```js
let questionHolder = document.getElementById("question-holder");
let scoreContainer = document.getElementById("score-container")
let answers = document.querySelectorAll(".answer");
let easyDifficulty = document.getElementById("easy-diff");
let mediumDifficulty = document.getElementById("medium-diff");
let hardDifficulty = document.getElementById("hard-diff");
let difficulty = document.getElementById("difficulty");
let difficultyLevel = "";
let questionCounter = 1;
let maxQuestion = 10
let currentQuiz = 0;
let score = 0;
let questionE1 = document.getElementById("question")
let a_answer = document.getElementById("a-answer");
let b_answer = document.getElementById("b-answer");
let c_answer = document.getElementById("c-answer");
let d_answer = document.getElementById("d-answer");
let submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");
let questions = [{
    question: `Al Pacino starred in the 1975 film Dog Day Afternoon that is the true story of a bank robbery gone bad. Where did the attempted robbery take place?`,
    a: `Chicago`,
    b: `Los Angeles`,
    c: `Boston`,
    d: `New York`,
    answer: `d`,
    difficulty: `hard`
  },

  {
    question: `Al Pacino and Robert De Niro have starred in a total of four movies together, can you name the film that they first shared screen time in?`,
    a: `Righteous Kill`,
    b: `Heat`,
    c: `The Godfather Part II`,
    d: `The Irishman`,
    answer: `b`,
    difficulty: `hard`
  },

  {
    question: `Al Pacino plays as Alphonse "Big Boy" Caprice in which 1990 film that is based on a comic strip that is actively running today?`,
    a: `Flash Gordon`,
    b: `The Phantom`,
    c: `Popeye`,
    d: `Dick Tracy`,
    answer: `d`,
    difficulty: `medium`
  },

  {
    question: `Al Pacino starred alongside which actor in The Devil's Advocate, that is known for films such as Point Break, Speed and The Matrix?`,
    a: `Keanu Reeves`,
    b: `Patrick Swayze`,
    c: `Jeff Daniels`,
    d: `Joe Pantoliano`,
    answer: `a`,
    difficulty: `medium`
  },
  {
    question: `Al Pacino starred as which character in the 1983 film Scarface?`,
    a: `Indiana Jones`,
    b: `James Bond`,
    c: `Tony Montana`,
    d: `Harry Potter`,
    answer: `c`,
    difficulty: `easy`
  },
  {
    question: `What is the name of the film that Al pacino has won his first and only Academy Award?`,
    a: `Dog Day Afternoon`,
    b: `The Godfather Part II`,
    c: `Serpico`,
    d: `Scent of a Woman`,
    answer: `d`,
    difficulty: `easy`

  }
]

let pickDifficulty = () => {
  if (easyDifficulty.checked) {
    difficultyLevel = "easy";
  } else if (mediumDifficulty.checked) {
    difficultyLevel = "medium";
  } else if (hardDifficulty.checked) {
    difficultyLevel = "hard";
  }
}
displayQuestion()

function displayQuestion() {

  let currentQuestion = questions[currentQuiz];
  questionE1.innerText = currentQuestion.question
  a_answer.innerText = currentQuestion.a
  b_answer.innerText = currentQuestion.b
  c_answer.innerText = currentQuestion.c
  d_answer.innerText = currentQuestion.d

  deselectAnswer()
}

difficulty.addEventListener("change", (evt) => {
  pickDifficulty()
  const filteredQuestions = questions.filter(question => question.difficulty === difficultyLevel)

  const quiztemplate = document.querySelectorAll('.quiz')
  const quizparent = quiztemplate[0].parentNode
  quiztemplate.forEach((qq => quizparent.removeChild(qq)))


  filteredQuestions.forEach((quiz) => {
    const quizquestion = quizparent.appendChild(quiztemplate[0].cloneNode(true));
    quizquestion.querySelector("#question").innerText = quiz.question
    quizquestion.querySelector("#a-answer").innerText = quiz.a
    quizquestion.querySelector("#b-answer").innerText = quiz.b
    quizquestion.querySelector("#c-answer").innerText = quiz.c
    quizquestion.querySelector("#d-answer").innerText = quiz.d
  })
}, true);

function selectedAnswer() {

  let answer = undefined;

  answers.forEach(answers => {
    if (answers.checked) {
      answer = answers.id;
    }
  })

  return answer
}

function deselectAnswer() {
  answers.forEach(answers => {
    answers.checked = false;
  });
}

function nextQuestion() {

  let answer = selectedAnswer();

  if (answer) {
    if (answer === quizquestion[currentQuiz].answer) {
      score++;
      document.getElementById('score-counter').innerHTML = `<h3>Score:${score} / ${maxQuestion}</h3>`
      giveMe.play();
    }

    currentQuiz++;
    if (currentQuiz < filteredQuestions.length) {
      displayQuestion();
      increaseQuestionCounter();
    } else endQuiz()
  }
}
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', nextQuestion);
```

```html
<div id="difficulty">
  <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="easy-diff" value="easy"> easy<br>
  <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="medium-diff" value="medium"> medium<br>
  <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="hard-diff" value="hard"> hard<br>
</div><br>

<div id="question-holder" class="hide">
  <div id="question-counter"></div>
  <div id="score-counter"></div>
  <p id="post"></p>
  <div class="quiz">
    <p id="question">Question placement</p>
    <ul>
      <li><label for="a" id="a-answer">possible answer</label><input type="radio" name="answer" id="a" class="answer"></li>
      <li><label for="b" id="b-answer">possible answer</label><input type="radio" name="answer" id="b" class="answer"></li>
      <li><label for="c" id="c-answer">possible answer</label><input type="radio" name="answer" id="c" class="answer"></li>
      <li><label for="d" id="d-answer">possible answer</label><input type="radio" name="answer" id="d" class="answer"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button id="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the (necessary) HTML?

Comment: Added it above.